# What are the data storage modes for paginated reports?

Tags: powerbi

For the normal Power BI reports we can have the data storage mode as either import, direct query, dual, or hybrid (+incremental).

What is the concept of data storage modes for paginated reports?

Answer (score 0):

Power BI reports are similar to DirectQuery.  Every time a user runs the report, the DataSet queries are run against the DataSources.

The query will be re-run if you change parameters and re-run, but not if you go through the pages.

Comment: So import mode and incremental refresh aren't supported for paginated reports?

Comment: If you want that you can write a paginated report against a Power BI Dataset that is in any storage mode.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports/report-builder-shared-datasets